# single_cat_title equivalent for custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have made a custom post type "projects" with custom taxonomy "tag", here's the snippet from code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'projects',

);

$qry = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( $qry->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <header class="archive-header">
                <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
```

single_cat_title as far as I think works with default categories, so what is the equivalent for custom taxonomy?

Comment: If any answer below answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For custom taxonomy terms, use [`single_term_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title)

> Displays or returns the term title for the current page.

Alternatively you can make use of `echo get_queried_object()->name`

Answer (score 1):

You want [`single_term_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_term_title#Description) I believe.

This is a more general function than [`single_cat_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title#Description) and is actually used by [`single_cat_title()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L968).